# Parse.com Node.js updating a user by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com's Javascript SDK. I'm trying to develop an admin function, where I can update a user. The following function is called with by retrieving updated values of a user object in a form.

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res){
    var userid = req.body.userid #id retrieved from user object

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(userid, {
        success: function (user) {
            user.set("name",req.body.name); #name retrieved from user object
            user.save();
            res.redirect("/home");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect("/home");
        }
    });
});
```

I've been trying with this codes and yet is returned with successful redirection without a clear indication of what the error is.

The console log for the Cloud Code server shows the following:

I2014-09-26T10:54:34.207Z] v001: Ran custom endpoint with:
  Input: {"method"=>"GET", "url"=>"/home" ...}
  Result: Success

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add an error callback to the save operation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you will need to check what the error was when saving. Also remember Parse.Object.save() is an asynchronous function, you don't want to redirect until the save succeeds.

```
app.post('/update', function(req, res) {
        var userid = req.body.userid;
        var pwd = req.body.pwd;
        Parse.User.logIn("userid", "pwd", {
            success: function (user) {
                user.set("username", "my_new_username");  // attempt to change username
                user.save(null, {
                    success: function (user) {
                        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                        query.get(userid, {
                            success: function (user) {
                                user.set("name", req.body.name);
                                user.save(null, {
                                    success: function (savedUserObject) {
                                        res.redirect('/home');
                                    },
                                    error: function (gameScore, error) {
                                        console.log('Failed to save object: ' + error.message);
                                        res.redirect('/error')
                                    }
                                });
                                res.redirect("/home");
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                res.redirect("/home");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }});
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Tom Erik Støwer for pointing out that there needs to be an error call in the .save() function. I've carried out the changes accordingly, and I've been directed to "/home" with an error message logged, "No Message provided" 

It seems that the first query.get function was not successful and the error callback is called. 

Just wondering if there is any restrictions in Parse from retrieving or updating a user's information without authenticating or logging in?

Comment: @harrybenjamin The parse user class is secured you will need to login with that user to save or modify the details. Will update my answer.